# How to use Google Analytics API to pull information for Channels (under Acquisition) in php?

Tags: php, facebook, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the Google Analytics API (PHP) to pull information regarding channels (predomidantley Facebook) into my system. Some of the information I would like to pull is number of sessions from each channel, the top landing pages, bounce rates etc etc however despite trying ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel and ga:channelGrouping on the query explorer nothing seems to be working.

I have looked elsewhere on the Google API documentation and trawled through various sites however I am either been told that no API currently exists for this currently or to use the above which doesn't appear to work.

Should the two dimensions/metrics above work and carry out what I want to do, if so how or is there currently no API available that will allow me to carryout what I need to do?

Thanks,

Comment: fwiw, I can't use ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel (I'm not sure if the query explorer supports all v4 features yet) , but ga:channelGrouping works fine. What does "nothing is working" entail exactly ? Do you get error messages, no results, wrong numbers for the channels... ?

Comment: In regards to ga:channelGrouping whereas the rest all appear in a menu box underneath when this one is copied or typed in I don't get the option, sorry I should have been more clear on that but it could be that It isn't supported

Answer (score 0):

The dimension `ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel` is a [V4 Cohort & lifetime Value dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts), which is only available for the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts) APIs. The query explorer is [built](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/src/javascript/query-explorer) with the [Core Reporting API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

Below I give the same sample request in JSON and PHP.

### JSON Cohort request

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:cohort"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers"
        }
      ],
      "cohortGroup": 
      {
        "cohorts": 
        [
          {
            "name": "cohort 1",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange": 
            {
              "startDate": "2015-08-01",
              "endDate": "2015-09-01"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cohort 2",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange": 
            {
              "startDate": "2015-07-01",
              "endDate": "2015-08-01"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### PHP Cohort Request

```
function cohortRequest(&$analyticsreporting) {
    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId("XXXX");

    $cohortDimension = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $cohortDimension->setName("ga:cohort");

    $acquisitionTrafficChannel = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $acquisitionTrafficChannel->setName("ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel");

    // Set the cohort dimensions
    $request->setDimensions(array($cohortDimension, $acquisitionTrafficChannel));

    $cohortActiveUsers = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $cohortActiveUsers->setExpression("ga:cohortActiveUsers");

    // Set the cohort metrics
    $request->setMetrics(array($cohortActiveUsers));

    $dateRange1 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange1->setStartDate("2015-08-01");
    $dateRange1->setEndDate("2015-09-01");

    // Create the first cohort
    $cohort1 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Cohort();
    $cohort1->setName("cohort_1");
    $cohort1->setType("FIRST_VISIT_DATE");
    $cohort1->setDateRange($dateRange1);

    $dateRange2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange2->setStartDate("2015-07-01");
    $dateRange2->setEndDate("2015-08-01");

    // Create the second cohort which only differs from the first one by the date range
    $cohort2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Cohort();
    $cohort2->setName("cohort_2");
    $cohort2->setType("FIRST_VISIT_DATE");
    $cohort2->setDateRange($dateRange2);

    // Create the cohort group
    $cohortGroup = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_CohortGroup();
    $cohortGroup->setCohorts(array($cohort1, $cohort2));

    $request->setCohortGroup($cohortGroup);

    // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
    $getReport = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $getReport->setReportRequests(array($request));

    // Call the batchGet method.
    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array($request) );
    $response = $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );

    printResults($response->getReports());
}
```

### Query explorer

As pointed out in the comments `ga:channelGrouping` is a standard V3 API dimension it should work fine in the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-12-30&end-date=2016-01-06&metrics=ga%3Asessions%2Cga%3Abounces&dimensions=ga%3AchannelGrouping). As you can see the [Query Explorer is designed to only list V3 Dimensions and Metrics](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/src/javascript/query-explorer/actions/select2-options.js#L135).